# How to let an ng-repeat list-item have it's own button and checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting a ToDo-List kata in JavaScript and have elected to use AngularJS because I'd like to become better at it.

[Github repo here](https://github.com/sanjsanj/todo_challenge)

This is my first iteration and I have two unordered-lists, one for active items and the other for completed items, each item should have its own delete-button and checkbox to indicate if it's active or complete.

The delete button works fine but the trouble has come when I've implemented the checkbox.  When I have multiple items and check one as complete it deletes the item description from the proceeding item and the delete buttons stop working.

As I say, I'm only just learning Angular and would love some advice on what I'm doing wrong please.

```
  <body ng-controller="ToDoListController as ctrl">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <div>

      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <input ng-model="newItem" id="newItem" type="text" placeholder="What needs doing?">
        <button ng-click="ctrl.addItem(newItem); newItem=''" class="btn" id="addNewItem">Add</button>
      </form>

      <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="activeItem in ctrl.listActive track by $index">
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="ctrl.toggle(activeItem)" ng-model="checkBoxModel.completed">
          {{activeItem}}
        <button ng-click="ctrl.deleteItem(activeItem)" class="btn" id="deleteItem">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="list-group" ng-repeat="completedItem in ctrl.listCompleted track by $index">
        <li>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="ctrl.toggle(completedItem)" ng-model="checkBoxModel.completed">
          {{completedItem}}
        <button ng-click="ctrl.deleteItem(completedItem)" class="btn" id="deleteItem">Delete</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </body>
```

My JS controller:

```
toDoList.controller('ToDoListController', [function(){
  this.listActive = [];
  this.listCompleted = [];

  var self = this;

  self.addItem = function(item){
    self.listActive.push(item);
  };

  self.isItemActive = function(item){
    return self.listActive.indexOf(item) >= 0;
  };

  self.deleteItem = function(item){

    if (self.isItemActive(item)) {
      self.listActive.splice(item, 1);
    } else {
      self.listCompleted.splice(item, 1);
    }
  };

  self.toggle = function(item){

    if (self.isItemActive(item)) {
      self.listCompleted.push(item);
      self.listActive.splice(item, 1);
    } else {
      self.listActive.push(item);
      self.listCompleted.splice(item, 1);
    }
  };

  self.editItem = function(item, newItem){

    if (self.isItemActive(item)) {
      var indexActive = self.listActive.indexOf(item);
      self.listActive[indexActive] = newItem;
    } else {
      var indexCompleted = self.listCompleted.indexOf(item);
      self.listCompleted[indexCompleted] = newItem;
    }
  };

  self.totalTaskCount = function(){
    return self.listActive.length + self.listCompleted.length;
  };

  self.activeTaskCount = function(){
    return self.listActive.length;
  };

  self.completedTaskCount = function(){
    return self.listCompleted.length;
  };

  self.clearCompleted = function(){
    self.listCompleted = [];
  };
}]);
```

Comment: much simpler if you use arrays of `task` **objects**...then bind the checkboxes to a property like `completed`. `ng-model` will add the properties automatically when they don't exist already. Then can use `ng-class` also based on properties...such as adding a strike-through for `completed` when it is true. Will see a reduction in controller code also once you set data models up as objects

Comment: also don't need 2 lists, just filter based on completed property ... again more simplification of what you actually need in controller code

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I decided to go a totally different way to complete this kata... but I am still curious as to how this problem could be solved.  I will revisit at some point.

Comment: your checkbox issue was related to binding all to same model property instance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using only one array of tasks. You can loop through this array with two ng-repeat blocks displaying only done items in one list and undone items in the other:

```
<body ng-app="bowling" ng-controller="ToDoListController as ctrl">
  <h3>ToDo:</h3>
  <ul ng-repeat="task in ctrl.taskList">
    <li ng-if="!task.done" ng-class="{classdone: task.done}">
      {{task.text}}
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done" ng-click="ctrl.toggleDone(task)"></input>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <h3>Done:</h3>
  <ul ng-repeat="task in ctrl.taskList">
    <li ng-if="task.done" ng-class="{classdone: task.done}">  {{task.text}} 
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="task.done" ng-click="ctrl.toggleDone(task)"></input>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <form>
    <input ng-model="taskText" type="text"></input>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.newTask(taskText)">Add Task</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

In your style sheet you can define the class .classdone now which gets applied if a task.done evaluates to true.

In your Controller:

```
toDoList.controller('ToDoListController', function(){

  this.taskList = [];
  self = this;

  this.newTask = function(taskText){
    var newTask = {done: false, text: ""};
    newTask.text = taskText;
    self.taskList.push(newTask)
  };

  this.toggleDone = function(task){
    if(task.done == true){
      task.done = false
    }else{
      task.done = true
    }
  };
});
```

The interesting Angular parts in this Kata:
- both lists in the view get updated automatically
- ng-if removes a task from the DOM if the given expression (task.done or !task.done) evaluates to false.

Let me know if there is anything unclear in this code.